# Dwarven Funeral Rites

Tags: wfrp-3e, wfrp-2e, wfrp-1e

Is there any good canon material on funeral rites for [dwarves](http://grammarist.com/usage/dwarfs-dwarves/) in Warhammer Fantasy Roleplay 1e, 2e, or 3e?

*[Dwarfs](http://grammarist.com/usage/dwarfs-dwarves/):Stone and Steel* by MadAlfred (Alfred Nuñez, Jr.) speaks a bit about the religion of the Dwarves in a 1e context. For 2e, it is touched on in *Karak Azgal*. However, nothing specific and all assumed "obvious."

Possibly, the Warhammer Fantasy Battle material speaks to specifics, but I do not have access to this.

Comment: +1 because it's concise, to the point, and showing personal research effort. One doesn't need to write a long question to make it a good question :)

Comment: I've done additional research and can answer my own question, however, others my wish to contribute. I'll give it a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to work from in WFRP 2e, but some research into WFRP 1e uncovered some good setting material and more for Dwarven funerals and last rites.

Consider the following quoted from *Apocrypha 2: Chart of Darkness*:

> Dwarfish funerals are intensely private affairs, and are normally attended only by close family. The normally take place in deep catacombs which the Dwarfs have constructed, so that the deceased can be laid to rest in the rock that gave them birth.
>
> According to local tradition in Middenheim, the cult of Morr once asked—very diplomatically—to be permitted to send a representative to observe a Dwarfish funeral in order to make sure that it provided the same protections against the risk of undead as a Morrish funeral. The following day, so the story goes, a sworn statement arrived at the Temple of Morr, signed by every Dwarf in the city and witnessed by thirty of Middenheim's most prominent lawyers. It stated absolutely that Dwarfs' funeral practices posed no threat to the city, necromantic or otherwise. A covering note signed by seventeen leaders of the Dwarf community offered to appoint a Priest of Gazul to visit the Temple of Morr and discuss the matter in detail if the Humans wished. They regretted, however, that it was out of the question for a non-Dwarf to attend a Dwarfish funeral. Sensing that the could precipitate a major diplomatic storm if the showed any sign of doubting the Dwarfs' word, the chief priests of Morr did not pursue the question further.

From this we can divine that Gazul, the Dwarf god of the Underearth, and his priests, are in charge of whatever last rites are performed. *Dwarfs: Stone and Steel* discusses Gazul in detail including strictures that reinforce Gazul priests:

1. Always oppose all defilers of the dead, especially necromancers
2. Never refuse burial rites for any that perish
3. Never enter or disturb a place of burial that has been blessed

Finally, there is the last paragraph:

> Clerics of Gazul may also use spells and rituals that are *functionally* identical to the following rites of the cult of Morr, described in *Apocrypha 2*: Funeral Rite, Nameless Funeral, Exorcism, Purification Rite.

The rites are rituals and would require specific work to convert to WFRP 2e (or WFRP 3e) and Dwarven setting material, to be *functionally* identical.